# Socket for push notification

Tags: socket.io, serversocket, python-sockets

For my current web (reactJS) app, i need to implement a push notification system. Backend APIs are written in  Python on Django Framework. So how should i  implement socket, should I write in python, or may I write in node or node for the client-side and python for the server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for Web push or mobile app? The term push is really synonymous with 'push notifications' meaning the client will get them even if the app / website is open or not.

If that is what you are looking for then you need to be looking at service workers and push notification servers.

If you want to simply send alerts to users on your page you can for sure use a simple websocket or long poll done in JS with a node server to emit to.